# Is this an acceptable use of eval()?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use an imploded string as an operator. And as a PHP novice, eval() is the only option that works, so far.

I've read other questions/answers on `eval()`. In most cases, people were trying to allow actual code input by the user, which is NOT what I'm doing here.

Here it is:

```
/*
 * Get user choices from a multiple-select customizer custom control.
 * Setting's choice values are the names of WordPress conditional tags.
 * Each choice set is given as 'key'=>'label' NOT 'key'=>'function'
 * so I'm limited to using strings here, e.g. is_front_page, is_singular.
 * The result will be a linear array, e.g. array( is_front_page, is_singular ).
 */
$conditions = get_theme_mod( 'theme_setting' );

/*
 * Here's where my trouble begins.
 * I need to append `()` to each array value using array_walk. */
array_walk( $conditions, function(&$value, $key) { $value = $value . '()'; });

/*
 * Next I implode the array values to insert the or operator
 * So instead of "is_front_page, is_singular", I'd end up with
 * "is_front_page() || is_singular()"
 */
$conditions = implode( ' || ', $conditions );

/* The previous step is NOT usable, in my novice experience, hence eval() */
eval( '$conditions =  ' . $conditions . ';');

/* Eval makes the following usable */
if( $conditions ) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

I'm hoping this is acceptable because I'm not allowing code input from the user and my theme setting is static so I can't actually do something like `$conditions === true` as a workaround.

Even if it is acceptable, please let me know if you have any advice on how to improve it.

Comment: I have already voted to move this to stackoverflow as this question is off topic here, and stackoverflow is the perfect place to ask question regarding generic php. I hope you will get an answer there :-)

Comment: I understand. However, I was hoping for answers specific to using WordPress conditionals as presented above.

Comment: @Rarst answered my question. Thanks Peter. I was too green to realize that WordPress conditionals had nothing to do with my question.

Comment: No problem. Glad that you got it solved. BTW, that is a great answer which I already upvoted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nooo... You are thinking too broadly. You have an array of function names and you jumped too far to executing them as *freeform* code.

Actually function names are valid *callbacks* and those are much safer and easier to execute with `call_user_func()`. So simply `array_map('call_user_func', $conditions)`  will turn all callbacks into their return values.

But note that your desired condition is of OR type. We don't need to run *every* callback, we only need to execute them until we get first `true` one.

This can be expressed as:

```
$result = array_reduce( $callbacks, function ( $carry, $callback ) {
    return $carry ?: (boolean) call_user_func( $callback );
}, false );
```

Comment: Thanks for helping =). I understand PHP at a rudimentary level and haven't found any tutorial series that help you grasp more advance concepts.